# Sequelize Multi Inserting Data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi everybody =) It's my first time using sequelize with postgresql, and I have problem with multi inserting data with sequelize(node.js). We have some tables(see in pic)

**Table Relations**

1) Clients -> 1:M -> Contracts

2) Contracts -> 1:M -> Contracts_attaches

3) Rates -> 1:M -> Contracts_attaches

[image: Test Tables]

**Clients Model**

```
const Client = db.define('clients', {
   id_clients: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
   },
   nclients: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
   }
 -some fields-
   createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE
   },
   updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE
   }
});
```

**Rate Model**

```
    const Rate = db.define('rates', {
       id_rates: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
       }
        --fields--
       createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
       },
       updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
       }
    })
```

**Contract Model**

```
    const Contract = db.define('contracts', {
       id_contracts: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false,
          autoIncrement: true,
          primaryKey: true
       },
       --fields--
       id_clients: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          allowNull: false
       },
       createdAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
       },
       updatedAt: {
          allowNull: false,
          type: Sequelize.DATE
       }
    })
```

**Contract_attach Model**

```
const Contract_attach = db.define('contract_attach', {
   id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
   },
   contracts_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references:{
         model:'contracts',
         key:'id_contracts'
      }
   },
   rate_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER

   },
   createdAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE
   },
   updatedAt: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.DATE
   },
})
```

**Association config**

```
Contract.belongsTo(Contract_attach, { foreignKey:'id_contracts', sourceKey:'contracts_id' });
Contract_attach.hasMany(Contract,{foreignKey:'id_contracts', sourceKey:'contracts_id'});
Contract_attach.hasMany(Rate,{foreignKey: 'id_rates', sourceKey: 'rate_id'});
Rate.belongsTo(Contract_attach, { foreignKey: 'rate_id', sourceKey: 'id_rates' });
```

**Example Inserting Data**

*I try insert data like this code*

```
Contract.create({'numcontract':22,'datereg':'2019-12-11','id_clients':5,Contract_attach:[{'rate_id':2,'rate_id':3}]},
            {include: [Contract_attach]}).then(result => console.log(result));
```

*or this code*

```
Contract.create({'numcontract':22,'datereg':'2019-12-11','id_clients':5,Contract_attach:[{'ratename':'Small Buissness','ratename':'Small Buissness 10'}]},
            {include: [Contract_attach]}).then(result => console.log(result));
```

When I try insert data with this code, sequelize inserting data just for **Contract** table, and ignoring insert to **Contract_attach**.

PS. **Rate** table have data, and we don't need insert data to the **Rate** table.

Comment: This is possible in 2 separate queries. You'll need to insert **Contract** row then upon success insertion do again for **Contract_attach**

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813467/sequelize-js-insert-a-model-with-one-to-many-relationship. Hope it will help!

Comment: Yes I read this refer, and this case dont work for me,may be my code contains logic error ;(

Comment: Yep dude, I basicly knewed about this solution. Just thought maybe there is another solution. @mas

Answer (score 0):

For some, it may and will be useful, but I solved this problem like this

```
Contr.create({'numcontract':22,'datereg':'2019-12-11','id_clients':5})
     .then(function(contr){   
                contract_att.bulkCreate([{'contracts_id':contr.id_contracts, 'rate_id':2},{'contracts_id':contr.id_contracts,'rate_id':3}]);  
            });
```

If you have another solution, pls share ))

Comment: As stated before, this solution is straight-forward and does the required. However, you might want to use [transactions](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html)  to rollback your first insert in case an error occurred in the second insert.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here

1. you said Contract > 1:M > Contract_attach then you write Contract_attach.hasMany(Contract...etc. it should be the other way around Contract.hasMany(Contract_attach...etc same goes for rates
2. In diagram there is relation between Contract_attach and rates but the define you didn't define this reference
3. Its not clear that columns rate_id and contract_id are nullable or not. based on that we can define if Contract_attach can or can not be belong to 2 different tables.

I think that the database schema need to change or explain why its in this way